Biometrics in case of a D visa issued by a European country
I have a non-EU passport and will be entering the EU on a D visa. How does immigration collect biometrics and where?
Will I be submitting fingerprints at the airport?
Does anyone have information about this?

IDK if it’s routine but I imagine they can and do. Why are you asking - what is your concern/problem? Does it make any difference whether they do or not?

Please do not use All Capital Letters.

@Traveller It makes a difference if you want to use someone else's passport, obviously.

EU law does not require the collection of fingerprints from applicants and holders of national D-type visas.
If you are required to request a residence permit (card) after entry,
EU law does require that residence permits issued in the uniform format contain at least two fingerprints (instead of 10 fingerprints required for short-term visa holders), unless the holder is exercising a free movement right, e.g. as family members of EU nationals. Each Member State is competent to decide in its national law on additional domestic requirements (e.g. additional fingerprints) regarding  population and identity document matters.
The fingerprints stored in the residence permits may be checked by any competent Schengen and EU authorities, but there is no EU-wide sharing of fingerprints collected from national visa or residence permit holders.
The processing of national visas and residence permit applications, including any possible collection of fingerprints under EU and national law, depends on the national authority in question and the itinerary you follow. The national authority can decide to collect the fingerprints abroad before or after the issuance of the visa, or decide to take the biometrics for residence permits at its own port of entry, or allow the collection at another appointment after entry, or decide not to collect fingerprints at all except in the cases prescribed by EU law.

Some countries like Estonia does collect Biometric for the D visa issued outside Estonia such as Digital nomad

@SaranshSharma Yes, but EU law does not require it. The processing procedure depends on the national authority.

EU border points are not all set up to do it routinely and systematically at the moment but I think it is supposed to come in the near future. Some automated passport control gates do it but that's not always the case either.
Many countries now collect biometrics specifically with the visa applications and those may be checked as well (presumably matching the person who presents themselves to the border to the person who made the visa application and not merely the data recorded on the passport RFID chip, if any).

The simple answer to you is if you have not provided biometrics meaning fingerprints at your home country then you are going to be doing that in the country who issued you D Visa and most probably at the immigration office not at the airport.
In  cases where you are permitted to convert your D Visa into a resident permit the embassy at your home country would skip the fingerprint and biometric only a Live Photo will be taken.


I want to ask if the immigration fingerprints you when you enter EU

As a visa national, your fingerprints have already been collected.
The Border Guards will take your fingerprints again to compare with your taken fingerprints if they have doubts about your identity or the authenticity of the visa.

Article 8 (Border checks on persons) (3)(b,c)
...
However, in all cases where there is doubt as to the identity of the holder of the visa and/or the authenticity of the visa, the VIS shall be consulted systematically using the number of the visa sticker in combination with the verification of fingerprints.


A lot of impressionistic reasoning as always. What's a “visa national”? As far as I know it's UK terminology and irrelevant here as we are talking about a long-stay visa. Collecting biometrics is common but how can you affirm it's been done given the huge diversity of type D visas that exist?

@Relaxed National visas (type D) are also entered into the VIS system.

I know that's possible but I did not comment on that one way or the other. Again, can you affirm that each and every type D visa is presently being entered with a full biometric record? What's your basis for this?
